# Correct YAML for Eslint - Value should NOT have more than 1 items - no-multiple-empty-lines

Tags: javascript, yaml, eslint

I am using Eslint on an existing project and the eslintrc is a YAML file; a format I'm not that familiar with. I am trying to set the rule `no-multiple-empty-lines` and having some success, but I get this error once I try to add multiple values to the rule as per documentation.

The rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines gets three options which can be set `max`, `maxBOF`, and `maxEOF`

So I am trying to set it as such:

```html
rules:
  no-multiple-empty-lines:
    - error
    - max: 1
    - maxBOF: 0
```

The error I am getting is:

`.eslintrc.yaml:
        Configuration for rule "no-multiple-empty-lines" is invalid:
        Value [{"maxBOF":0},{"max":1}] should NOT have more than 1 items.`

From my understanding the first line is error/warn but the second is the options.

How do I set multiple options correctly on the second indent so that I can have both maxBOF and max without throwing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to set multiple options is without additional `-`, you can pass a map to a list as I found here: [Idiot's Guide to YAML](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot's-introduction-to-yaml#lists)

```html
rules:
  no-multiple-empty-lines:
    - error
    - max: 1
      maxBOF: 0
```